# How to convert mathematical matrix to Direct3D matrix?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, rotation, direct3d

When representing a mathematical matrix, rotations are performed as follows:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

```
Rx(θ) = 1  0      0
        0  cos θ  -sin θ
        0  sin θ  cos θ

Ry(θ) = cos θ  0  sin θ
        0      1  0
        -sin θ 0  cos θ

Rz(θ) = cos θ  -sin θ  0
        sin θ  cos θ   0
        0      0       1
```

However, I've discovered that Direct3D uses the transpose of these rotation matrices.

In my app I have a generic Matrix class which uses the standard mathematical rotation representations. With a simple rotation about 1 axis, it is easy to convert to a Direct3D matrix, as you can just do the transposition. However, if you rotate about x, y and then z you cannot simply get the transposed matrix.

My question is, how can I convert a mathematical matrix in to a Direct3D matrix?

Here is an example:

> Matrix matrix;
>   matrix.RotateX(1.0f);
>   matrix.RotateY(1.0f);
>   matrix.RotateZ(1.0f);
>
> Mathematical matrix =
>           m_11    0.29192656    float
>           m_12    -0.45464867    float
>           m_13    0.84147096    float
>           m_14    0.00000000    float
>           m_21    0.83722234    float
>           m_22    -0.30389664    float
>           m_23    -0.45464867    float
>           m_24    0.00000000    float
>           m_31    0.46242565    float
>           m_32    0.83722234    float
>           m_33    0.29192656    float
>           m_34    0.00000000    float
>           m_41    0.00000000    float
>           m_42    0.00000000    float
>           m_43    0.00000000    float
>           m_44    1.0000000    float
>
> Direct3D matrix =
>         _11 0.29192656  float
>         _12 0.45464867  float
>         _13 -0.84147096 float
>         _14 0.00000000  float
>         _21 -0.072075009    float
>         _22 0.88774973  float
>         _23 0.45464867  float
>         _24 0.00000000  float
>         _31 0.95372111  float
>         _32 -0.072075009    float
>         _33 0.29192656  float
>         _34 0.00000000  float
>         _41 0.00000000  float
>         _42 0.00000000  float
>         _43 0.00000000  float
>         _44 1.0000000   float

**Edit**: Here are some examples of individual rotations.

**X-Axis rotation by 1 radian**
*My matrix class:*

```
1.0000000    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
0.00000000   0.54030228   -0.84147096    0.00000000
0.00000000   0.84147096    0.54030228    0.00000000
0.00000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    1.0000000
```

*Direct3D:*

```
1.0000000    0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
0.00000000   0.54030228    0.84147096    0.00000000
0.00000000  -0.84147096    0.54030228    0.00000000
0.00000000   0.00000000    0.00000000    1.0000000
```

As you can see, the Direct3D matrix is exactly the transpose of my matrix class (my class gives the same results as the examples given by Wikipedia at the top of this question).

Comment: you know, DirectX does provide functions for doing rotation matrices for you and generally, you will want to be using quternians (sp?) for rotations rather then matrices as you avoid gimbals lock

Comment: Using quaternions doesn't implicitly solve gimbal lock problems, and using matrices doesn't neccesarily mean you have gimbal lock problems - it's about the operations you do on them.

Comment: Yes I realise this, but I'm writing generic classes that can be used with multiple renderers. Thanks.

Comment: Erm ... is it me or does this question answer itself?  You transpose from column major to row major order (or vice versa).  Its a pretty simple operation ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always traced this confusion back to the late 80s.  As I remember it, there were two particularly influential books on graphics at the time.  One of them wrote vectors as row vectors on the left of matrices; the book was quite hardware oriented - conceptually you thought of the vectors as flowing left-to-right through a pipeline of transform matrices.  Rendermorphics (which was later picked up by Microsoft to become Direct3D) went down this route.  The other book wrote vectors as column vectors on the right of matrices, which is the way OpenGL does it (and I think most mathematicians would naturally gravitate towards this, although I have met exceptions).

However, both approaches are entirely equally valid mathematics!  If you're confused by Direct3D, start thinking in terms of writing row vectors on the left of matrices, not in terms of transposing the matrices.

You're not the first person to be confused by [this](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=511061) (see [also](http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=direct3d+row+vectors&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=)).

Comment: Hi timday, thanks for that. Can you explain further the comment "start thinking in terms of writing row vectors on the left of matrices"?

Comment: Thanks for those links, does that indicate that Direct3D is row vectors and the Wikipedia examples were written with column vectors?

Comment: Yes if you look at the Direct3D docs on transforms, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206269(VS.85).aspx it clearly uses row vectors on the left of the matrices, whereas OpenGL (like the wikipedia articles) uses column vectors; see http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml In the long run, it's best to understand the difference and work in the systems "as intended".

Comment: So as my Matrix class is apparently column vector based, shouldn't it be a simple transpose to get a row vector based matrix? As that doesn't appear to be working right now...

Comment: The consequences of row vectors on the left vs column vectors on the right go beyond just transposition.  It affects the order transforms are written for composition too.  More formally: (AB)^T = (B^T)(A^T) (or something like that; it's been a while).

Answer (score 1):

The DirectX matrix classes are an implementation of a mathematical matrix.

The handedness only exhibits itself when you do operations on it such as rotation.
The transpose should give you the result you are looking for as long as the same operations are done on both the DIrectX matrix and your 'mathematical matrix'. My guess is that there's a difference in the implementations of rotation, or the order the rotations are being done differs.

Comment: The rotations are being performed in the same order. As I mentioned in the question, if you do a RotateX on a Direct3D matrix, the result is the transpose of a "mathematical" matrix.

Comment: I'm saying that if the only difference is where the numbers are being read from and written to, they should always be the transpose.

Comment: I'm thinking the difference may be the handed-ness of Direct3D.

Comment: Check each of the rotations separately, and see if one differs.

Comment: Yes, I've just read this article about handedness of Direct3D and they recommend scaling the z values by -1.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324490%28VS.85%29.aspx - But I tried that and I don't see anything at all now.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the only terms off of the prime diagonal are of the form *±sin ( θ )* and that *sin ( -θ ) = - sin ( θ )* but *cos ( -θ ) = cos ( θ )*, the relationship between Direct3D and the Wikipedia maths can also be seen as an opposite interpretation of the direction of the angle.

Comment: Are you saying that stuff rotates the other way around in Direct3D?

Comment: Yes that'd be a consequence of it's left-handed coordinate system.  Mathematics invariably follows a right-handed convention.